# How to compare a char?

Tags: c, char, conditional-statements, assignment-operator

I am learning c. I have a question. Why doesn't my program work?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

char cmd;

void exec()
{
        if (cmd == "e")
        {
                printf("%c", cmd);
                // exit(0);
        }
        else
        {
                printf("Illegal Arg");
        }
}

void input()
{
        scanf("%c", &cmd);
        exec();
}

int main()
{
        input();
        return 0;
}
```

I insert a "e" but it says illegal arg.
cmd is not equal to "e". Why? I set cmd with scanf to "e".

Comment: use `cmd == 'e'` instead, and read up on `C` before you ask these questions. It's generally frowned upon if you ask a question that could be answered in a begginner's book

Comment: Oh, and you also haven't compiled with warnings enabled, have you.

Comment: @user2603035 - sorry you're being treated so poorly :(  As Taylor Flores said, a "char" is not a "string"; you need to substitute `if (cmd == 'e')`

Comment: @paulsm4 No, he needs `if (cmd == 'e')`.

Comment: To OP: you better avoid using `scanf()`. Instead, `fgets()` and `fgetc()` are your friends.

Comment: Your problem is that `"e"` is not a character, it's a character *string*.  For the character do `'e'`.

Comment: +1 to the OP for a well-specified question. The very reason stackoverflow exists is because sometimes we cannot see the problem that lies infront of our own eyes, even though the book has all the information. Don't hesitate to ask more questions. We will make sure you learn programming faster than you would if you were left alone with just a book! :)

Comment: Albeit, it is an entry level question, it's one of the facets that is strange with C, the fact that we don't really have strings in the same manner as higher level languages, Its not intuitive for say a developer used to JavaScript that the string literals are not really related to each other. The question could be better formed, however.

Comment: It's a shame that OP earns as much reputation with this poor question as I may with one moderately good answer. It's just a shame.

Comment: @H2CO3 how are you going to handle it when the OP *answers* his first question!? ;-)

Comment: @H2CO3 Did you notice a lot of moderator comment deletion going on.

Comment: @randomstring I don't see how that's related. Answering a question shows knowledge. But asking a bad question only shows laziness. Let he get 1000 upvotes for his first answer if he deserves it, I don't care.

Comment: @Armin I did, obviously. Moderators support laziness.

Comment: `cmd == "e"`, where `cmd` is of type `char` is illegal (more precisely, a constraint violation). Any conforming compiler must at least warn about the type mismatch. Did you get a warning from your compiler?

Comment: @H2CO3; Now I am gonna ask **Why moderators support laziness** and I am sure it will boost my reputation ;)

Comment: @haccks (At least on Meta :P )

Comment: @H2CO3 the "equals" tag on the question is priceless! can't say the rep isn't well-deserved ;-) seriously, i was being humorous about how you would react if the OP gave a *bad* answer and it somehow got a lot of rep. we'd have to send someone to check on you ;-) all's good. you have been quite helpful to OP in your first few comments and that's nice!

Comment: @KeithThompson; You are right but some older compilers(like Turbo C++) will not show this warning.

Comment: @randomstring (Why was I thinking about the "equals" tag? :P )

Comment: @H2CO3 i realize the equals tag must have been lonely!

Comment: @haccks: Is there any reason to use such old compilers? And if there is, does Turbo C++ (hopefully operating in C mode) have an option to make it warn about this kind of thing?

Comment: @KeithThompson; Sir, this compiler is still being used in some engineering colleges, institutions and I think the only reason behind this is professors/lecturer  in these institutions have not upgraded themselves and they are forcing students to use this obsolete compiler ( I am also the victim of this).

Comment: @haccks: Rephrase: Is there any *good* reason to use such old compilers?

Comment: @KeithThompson; No. I think there is not any good reason to use such old compilers specially after c99 standardization. But still some people are using this (I have explained the reason in my previous comment)!!!

Comment: @haccks Some new users just bother about getting answers, they don't feel it worthy enough of being accepted. They should at least show respect to the time which respondents put on answering the question. I had this one answer too , I was patient and answered and advised OP to ask something when done with full research himself ....... but it still hangs there unaccepted . What to do ? ... mine is one others will be having 100s of answrs like that .

Comment: @haccks poor user is not even aware his question got so much attention! i think he has not checked back on SO. oh the lost labor of code.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

First of, in C single quotes are char literals, and double quotes are string literals.
Thus, 'C' and "C" are not the same thing.

To do string comparisons, use strcmp.

```
const char* str = "abc";
if (strcmp ("abc", str) == 0) {
   printf("strings match\n");
}
```

To do char comparisons, use the equality operator.

```
char c = 'a';
if ('a' == c) {
   printf("characters match\n");
}
```

Comment: In your second example, you declare and define `c` as `'a'` but use the variable name `a` to compare to `'a'`. That variable name should, of course, be `c`. :)

Answer (score 2):

`cmd` is a char type but `"e"` is a string not a char type,you should write like this `if(cmd == 'e')`